# Create custom keyboard shortcuts in GBoard in iOS

Tags: ios, keyboard, autocorrect, auto-complete

I know it is possible to create custom keyboard shortcuts with the default keyboard (General > Keyboard > Text Replacement). Can the same thing be done on GBoard for iOS?

For example, per [this tip](https://www.reddit.com/r/lifehacks/comments/clm491/set_an_autocorrect_shortcut_for_as_your_email/), I would like to set `@@` to autocorrect to my email address.

Comment: See tip 12 at https://ios.gadgethacks.com/how-to/20-tips-help-you-master-gboard-for-iphone-0182301/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create keyboard shortcuts with GBoard, it just uses the default apple keyboard shortcuts. If you go to `Settings -> General -> Keyboard -> Text Replacement`, you can create shortcuts by tapping the `+` symbol and entering the phrases and shortcuts.

Comment: For some reason that wasn't working for me before. Now it is!

Comment: It doesn't work for me. Gboard just ignores default apple keyboard shortcuts

Comment: That is also happening to me. What's odd is that it has worked before.